# How does PUN2 synchronize character movements in multiplayer VR scenarios (not simple animation)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**My problem**: I use the Mediapipe solution to capture the motion of the character with the camera, but I found that when I use PUN2 for synchronization, I can only synchronize the walking movement of the character through Animation. Once I start using motion capture, PUN2 can’t control the character The body movements are synchronized.

**The reason I guess**: Animator cannot be turned on when the motion capture code is active, so I turned off Animator in the code. However, I only have the Transform and Animator of the entire Avatar in my Phonton View, so PUN2 cannot synchronize the movements of the character's specific limbs after the motion capture code is turned on.
[only have the Transform and Animator of the entire Avatar in my Phonton View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnIaV.png)
[Animator cannot be turned on when the motion capture code is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcYei.png)

**I wonder if there is any workaround**? I saw someone call IPunObservable and OnPhotonSerializeView() in the script, should I adopt this solution, and how to do it?